# input stream with string

Tags: c++

If I type `john` when prompted for a char, the while statement will loop 4 times, one for each letter of john, before it asks again for user input.

Why does this program do not allow me insert more input before the whole 4 chars of john are consumed ? I would expect it to discard the 3 remaining letters of the string john and asked me for more input on the second loop.

The whole example can be found at page 44 of Bjarne Stroustrup The C++ Programming Language 4th edition.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool question() {
  while (true) {
    cout << "Continue ?\n";
    char answer = 0;
    cin >> answer;
    cout << "answer: " << answer << endl;
  }
  return false;
}

int main () {
  cout << question() << endl;
}
```

The output becomes:

```bash
Continue ?
john
answer: j
Continue ?
answer: o
Continue ?
answer: h
Continue ?
answer: n
Continue ?
```

Comment: What does "seems to be ignored" mean? What did you mean by that?

Comment: It's not ignored.  You set it to `0`, then you read in the next character still in the input stream and that `0` gets overwritten by said input.

Comment: That it is ignored to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: ***Would love to know why people spend time downvoting instead of answering the legitimate question.*** I did not downvote. However I say probably because the question is a little unclear and the code example is not optimal. There are several issues  with the code like not using the `answer` variable other than printing, the infinite loop, and returning false unconditionally that further cloud the question. Also nothing is ignored. Maybe you can explain why you think `char answer = 0;` is ignored and what you expected to happen.

Comment: @Eduardo it's quite unclear what you're actually expecting that code to do with your input. As far I can tell, everything you show works exactly like expected. I did downvote hence.

Comment: I think you are missing the point of the downvote. If you improve your question to make it a better question then the downvotes would likely go away and perhaps you will get upvotes. The downvote means that the people voting don't think the question will be a good fit for the site. Remember the #1 purpose of a question at StackOverflow is to help future readers solve the same problem. If we are having a difficulty understanding understanding the question as experienced programmers we expect future readers to have a similar problem.

Comment: Why do you believe that everyone should immediately understand what "seems to be ignored" means? This is like calling your auto mechanic and describing your problem as "my car seems to be not moving forward", and expecting a complete diagnosis in return. Instead of explaining your impressions, it would've been more useful to state: 1) the actual observed results, and 2) the exact results you were expecting. You did 1, but forgot to explain 2. We're not mind readers, so we have no idea what you meant by "seems to be ignored", this is not a useful problem description.

Comment: @eduardo well, how would you consider your misunderstandings  about how `std::cin >>` is working being helpful for others, who were already reading the relevant documentation, before landing at your question here at research?

Comment: If you use a debugger to step through the code, you should see that `char answer = 0;` is not ignored.

Comment: I have edited the question to remove possible ambiguity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be wondering why you're not being allowed to enter a character at each prompt. You have entered four characters into the input stream, so your loop runs four times to consume all of that input.

If you only want to use the first character in the input, you may want to get an entire line and work on just the first character.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

bool question() {
  while (true) {
    std::cout << "Continue ?\n";
    std::string line;
    std::getline(std::cin, line);
    std::cout << "answer: " << line[0] << endl;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Of course, you should also check that an empty line was not entered, which may be as simple as checking if `line[0]` is not `'\0'`.

Comment: FWIW since C++11 `line[0]` will always work.  If the string is empty then you will get a null terminator.

Comment: @NathanOliver: IIRC it worked prior to C++11 as well.... The address of the terminator didn't have to be contiguous with the rest of the string unless `c_str()` had been called, but just reading it using `operator[]` was perfectly fine.

Comment: @BenVoigt In C++08/03 it was legal for a `const std::string` but UB otherwise.  [source: 21.3.4 basic_string element access](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1804.pdf)

Comment: @NathanOliver: Ahh yes, can't have programmers overwriting the shared terminator storage.  Still, that doesn't require `const std::string`, it just requires a `const std::string&`